# cmake: hierarchical project setup

Tags: cmake

I have a project with the following structure:

```
proj:
-CMakeLists.txt    
-subdir0   
  -CMakeLists.txt    
  -app0.cpp
  -app1.cpp
-subdir1
  -CMakeLists.txt    
  -app2.cpp
```

And after build, I like to have:

```
proj:    
-CMakeLists.txt    
-subdir0   
  -CMakeLists.txt    
  -app0.cpp
  -app1.cpp
-subdir1
  -CMakeLists.txt    
  -app2.cpp
-build
  -subdir0   
    -app0.exec
    -app1.exec
  -subdir1
    -app2.exec
```

The CMake doc is quite difficult to read and all I need here is an example (e.g. an existing project) how to set this up...

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

You want the following:

proj/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MyTest)
add_subdirectory(subdir0)
add_subdirectory(subdir1)
```

proj/subdir0/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(app0 app0.cpp)
add_executable(app1 app1.cpp)
```

proj/subdir1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(app2 app2.cpp)
```

Then in a command prompt simply do:

```
mkdir <root of proj>/build
cd <root of proj>/build
cmake ..
```